# AWS Graphql API mutation does not update DataStore

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, graphql-mutation

I'm not able to update the existing data on AWS Graphql API. Here are my files.

Schema

```js
type PersonalInfo @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  middleName: String
  lastName: String!
  dateOfBirth: String!
  primaryLanguage: String!
  countryOfBirth: String!
  gender: String!
  maritalStatus: String!
}
```

mutation

```js
export const updatePersonalInfo = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdatePersonalInfo(
    $input: UpdatePersonalInfoInput!
    $condition: ModelPersonalInfoConditionInput
  ) {
    updatePersonalInfo(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      firstName
      middleName
      lastName
      dateOfBirth
      primaryLanguage
      countryOfBirth
      gender
      maritalStatus
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      _version
      _deleted
      _lastChangedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

My update function

```js
const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

    try {
      const result = await API.graphql({
        query: updatePersonalInfo,
        variables: {
          input: {
            id: currentUser.attributes.sub,
            firstName: data.firstName,
            middleName: data.middleName,
            lastName: data.lastName,
            dateOfBirth: data.dateOfBirth,
            primaryLanguage: data.primaryLanguage,
            countryOfBirth: data.countryOfBirth,
            gender: data.gender,
            maritalStatus: data.maritalStatus
          }
        }
      });
```

I'm able to create a new model, but not able to update it. From network tab I see that I send the new first name for example but in the successful response but with the previous name that was on dataStore.

I'm new to AWS Amplify, any help would be appreciated.

Request Payload:
[image]

Response Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the contributors and they gave me the solution on [github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10664) which is not currently in their documentations. Basically we have to pass the `_version` in the request. We first have to query to get the `_version` and the send it back when we want to update the database.

```js
try {
      const result = await API.graphql({
        query: updatePersonalInfo,
        variables: {
          input: {
            ...
            _version: data._version
          }
        }
      });
```

Just in case if you need to know how to get the _version value, here is the sample code:

```js
  const _getPersonalInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      return await API.graphql({
        query: getPersonalInfo,
        variables: {id: currentUser.attributes.sub}
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
  };


_getPersonalInfo().then((response: any) => {
    const _version = response.data.getPersonalInfo._version;
}
```

Comment: I owe you a coffee, Hamid! I have spent hours trying to solve this. Thanks!